# Drawing automata paths step by step with TikZ and \onslide command

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, paths, automata

I have an oral presentation on friday, where I will have to explain the determinization process for transducers. To save time, and make the whole thing clearer, I'd like to do a step by step construction with beamer and TikZ, instead of drawing the whole thing on the board.

So far, I've easily managed to make nodes appear step by step with the `\onslide` command, but when it comes to transitions, the `\onslide` command doesn't seem to work anymore, I get plenty of compilation errors.

Here's my code so far, don't pay attention to the `\onslide` numbering not starting at 1, it's just because I have a few things appearing before the construction of the actual automaton.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.6,every node/.style={transform shape},node distance=1.5cm]
  \onslide<3->{\node[state] (3a) {3,a};}
  \onslide<7->{\node[state] (2b) [above right=of 3a] {2,b};}
  \onslide<4->{\node[state] (3c) [above=of 2b] {3,c};}
  \onslide<6->{\node[state] (1d) [below right=of 3a] {1,d};}
  \onslide<5->{\node[state] (3e) [below=of 1d] {3,e};}

  \path[->]
  \onslide<8->{(3a) edge [loop above] node {\textcolor<8>{red}{0|a}} ()}
  \onslide<9->{(3c) edge [bend left] node {\textcolor<9>{red}{0|c}} (3a)}
  \onslide<10->{(3e) edge [bend left] node {\textcolor<10>{red}{0|e}} (3a)};        
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a way to do what I want, other than drawing a complete, different automata for each transition, and then print each one of these automaton with the `\onslide` command to get the step by step thing?

I could also print the final automata directly, and use the `\textcolor` command to make nodes and transitions invisible, and then visible again on specific slides, but I'm not very pleased with that solution.

Thanks in advance to anyone who will read and answer this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.

Comment: And for Beamer, also, it is especially important as there are lots of config options, themes and templates. You know that transparency etc. in Beamer is basically a matter of colouring things in like the background, anyway, right? So colouring probably ends up in any solution somehow, even if only implicitly.